Extract variable number of property values from a JSON Array in a Query Activity
Wondering if anyone working in SFMC/Marketing Cloud Engagement has a method for extract a variable number of array property values from a JSON string in a Data Extension row.
I'm aware that the ideal solution leverages the OPENJSON library/function, but it isn't supported in the platform.
Here's my brute-force method that works. I would love to not hard-code a fixed number of array elements in JSON string (the # of union-ed sub-queries below).
Is there a shorter, scalable method that I can leverage?
CREATE TABLE SubscriberRoles
    ( subscriberKey varchar(255), roles varchar(max))
;
INSERT INTO SubscriberRoles
     (subscriberKey,roles)
VALUES
     ('12345','[{"Category":"Accounting","City":"Denver","State":"CO","Zip":"12345"},{"Category":"Management","City":"Denver","State":"CO","Zip":"12345"}]')
   , ('24680','[{"Category":"Accounting","City":"Kansas City","State":"MO","Zip":"66555"},{"Category":"Sanitation","City":"Kansas City","State":"KS","Zip":"66866"},{"Category":"IT","City":"Springfield","State":"MO","Zip":"71234"}]')     
   , ('35790','[{"Category":"IT","City":"Springfield","State":"MO","Zip":"71234"}]')     

select
  si.subscriberkey
, i.Category
, i.City
, i.State
, i.Zip
from SubscriberRoles as si
left join (

        select subscriberkey, json_value(roles, '$[0].Category') as Category, json_value(roles, '$[0].City') as City, json_value(roles, '$[0].State') as State, json_value(roles, '$[0].State') as Zip from SubscriberRoles
  union select subscriberkey, json_value(roles, '$[1].Category') as Category, json_value(roles, '$[1].City') as City, json_value(roles, '$[1].State') as State, json_value(roles, '$[1].State') as Zip from SubscriberRoles
  union select subscriberkey, json_value(roles, '$[2].Category') as Category, json_value(roles, '$[2].City') as City, json_value(roles, '$[2].State') as State, json_value(roles, '$[2].State') as Zip from SubscriberRoles
  union select subscriberkey, json_value(roles, '$[3].Category') as Category, json_value(roles, '$[3].City') as City, json_value(roles, '$[3].State') as State, json_value(roles, '$[3].State') as Zip from SubscriberRoles
  union select subscriberkey, json_value(roles, '$[4].Category') as Category, json_value(roles, '$[4].City') as City, json_value(roles, '$[4].State') as State, json_value(roles, '$[4].State') as Zip from SubscriberRoles

) i on i.subscriberkey = si.subscriberkey

where 1=1
and i.Category is not null


Output



subscriberkey
Category
City
State
Zip




12345
Accounting
Denver
CO
CO


12345
Management
Denver
CO
CO


24680
Accounting
Kansas City
MO
MO


24680
IT
Springfield
MO
MO


24680
Sanitation
Kansas City
KS
KS


35790
IT
Springfield
MO
MO



Try it yourself: dbfiddle
